# Disable multi-lingual search in Azure Search

Tags: azure-search

What's the best/easiest way to disable multi-lingual search in Azure, so only English content is indexed? I have language fallback turned on, but turning that off wouldn't disable multi-lingual. I didn't know if there was a config setting to do it, or some setting in the Azure portal for it.

One colleague pointed me to this article: https://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2015/10/fix-for-multiple-versions-of-items.html. It's not exactly what I'm looking to do, but would this generally be the approach, to basically say if the item language is not English, just skip the indexing?

Comment: check this answer once.https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15538/index-the-content-for-some-of-the-languages-sitecore-azure-index

Comment: This actually did the trick...if you want to put it in as an answer, I can credit you.

Comment: Credit should goes to @G Killian. He answered at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just disable a language. I had a similar requirement once for a custom index, and had to write my own crawler to achieve this.

The benefit of a crawler approach is that you can set this per index (which is not possible with the inbound filters). Wrote a blog post with code) on this https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/10/custom-sitecore-index-crawler.html (dated 2016, so might need some updates in the code).

What I actually did was check the code from the original SitecoreItemCrawler, created a class overwriting it and adapted where needed - especially overwrite `DoAdd` and `DoUpdate`.